# Azure - how to delete a blob completely using cli commands

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, azure-blob-storage

I am building an automation script and I need to delete a blob and all its snapshots if any, as one of the last steps. All the other commands are working fine as I have used az ad sp create-for-rbac --name myRBACuser for authentication.
However the blob deletion command I use, seems to time out.
My command and it's output, as executed within a Linux machine in Azure cloud is as follows:

```
$ az storage blob delete --container-name lhbox --name lighthouse.vhd --account-name ramesh1storage1.blob.core.windows.net --auth-mode login

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ramesh1storage1.blob.core.windows.net.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /lhbox/lighthouse.vhd (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fd7372ac780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

I get the same result when I try the command from my desktop Powershell.
I am new to azure and perhaps I am not using the right method. Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--account-name` argument should only include `ramesh1storage1`, and not include the `blob.core.windows.net` domain. For example the command should look like:

```sh
$ az storage blob delete --container-name lhbox --name lighthouse.vhd --account-name ramesh1storage1 --auth-mode login
```

Typically when I evaluate a network timeout I inspect where my system is trying to communicate, and make sure that a connection is possible. The exception host gave me the clue: `host='ramesh1storage1.blob.core.windows.net.blob.core.windows.net'`.

Comment: Thank you very much @joncloud. I had to remove the "--auth-mode login" since it said I don't have permissions. After removing it did the deletion after a small complaint.